# AngularJS HTTP POST doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I have to send a simple JSON object using Angular JS thorough a HTTP POST.

I have a simple ng-clik linked function:

```
$scope.requestGoogleAuth = function() {
        var googleCredentials = {
            email: 'user@domain.com',
            password: 'a2s4d'
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(googleCredentials));
        /*$http({
            url: '/MyServlet',
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(googleCredentials),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })*/
        $http.post("/MyServlet", JSON.stringify(googleCredentials)).then(function success(response) {
            $('#loginGoogleModal').modal('hide');
            $("#notificationsWrapper").notify(
                "Logged with Google",
                {
                    className: 'success',
                    position: 'bottom right'
                }
            );
            $scope.googleLogged = true;
            console.log($scope.googleLogged);
        }, function error(response) {
            $('#loginGoogleModal').modal('hide');
            $("#notificationsWrapper").notify(
                "Failed to login with Google",
                {
                    className: 'error',
                    position: 'bottom right'
                }
            );
            $scope.googleLogged = false;
            console.log($scope.googleLogged);
        });

    };
```

My controller configuration is:

```
iftttApp.controller('indexController', 
                    ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$window', '$http', function ($scope, $routeParams, $window, $http, ) { ... });
```

The POST reaches successfully my servlet returning success, however the JSON isn't put in the HTTP message, the POST data results empty. Why?

Comment: My controller configuration is:

`iftttApp.controller('indexController',  ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$window', '$http',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $window, $http, ) { ... });`

Comment: "the JSON isn't put in the HTTP message, the POST data results empty" — How are you determining this? Are you using the developer tools in the browser to examine the network traffic? Are you trying to read it with some server side Java that you didn't include in the question?

Comment: $scope.nome and $scope.regione are defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. actually your posting not a proper key pair,values as json in your post request.

```
$scope.requestGoogleAuth = function() {
        var googleCredentials = {
            email: 'user@domain.com',
            password: 'a2s4d'
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(googleCredentials));
        /*$http({
            url: '/MyServlet',
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(googleCredentials),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })*/

        var postvalue = {
            "nome": $scope.nome,
            "regione": $scope.regione
        }
        $http.post("/MyServlet", angular.toJson(postvalue)).then(function success(response) {
            $('#loginGoogleModal').modal('hide');
            $("#notificationsWrapper").notify(
                "Logged with Google",
                {
                    className: 'success',
                    position: 'bottom right'
                }
            );
            $scope.googleLogged = true;
            console.log($scope.googleLogged);
        }, function error(response) {
            $('#loginGoogleModal').modal('hide');
            $("#notificationsWrapper").notify(
                "Failed to login with Google",
                {
                    className: 'error',
                    position: 'bottom right'
                }
            );
            $scope.googleLogged = false;
            console.log($scope.googleLogged);
        });

    };
```

Comment: it seems you are posting a string, not a json object

Comment: thats why i am converting it to JSON using angular.toJson(). it works for me.

Comment: I correct the code, tested also "angular.toJson(googleCredentials)", but not working.

Comment: could please check the networking tool in your browser POST body information. and also how you are receiving the json values in server end?